# PHP MySQL PDO how to fetch all CID that related to same column

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

i have a login script that use discord outh but in the database each player can have many characters so im using discord column as identifier and im trying to print all CID that related to same discord id
for example player1 have 3 characters so once player1 logged in he must see a clickable text like
cid1 cid2 cid3
if he click on cid2 for example than show all info about his cid 2 which is

(4, 'YTS46301', '555555555555555555', 2, 'player1')

or if he click on cid3 print the this

(2, 'ZAZ11111', '555555555555555555', 3, 'player1')

so here is database

```sql
CREATE TABLE `players` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `citizenid` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `discord` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `cid` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb3;

ALTER TABLE `players`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`citizenid`),
  ADD KEY `id` (`id`),
  ADD KEY `discord` (`discord`);

INSERT INTO `players` (`id`, `citizenid`, `discord`, `cid`, `name`) VALUES
(1, 'TPT54548', '555555555555555555', 1, 'player1'),
(2, 'ZAZ11111', '555555555555555555', 3, 'player1'),
(3, 'UGH53311', '333333333333333333', 1, 'player2'),
(4, 'YTS46301', '555555555555555555', 2, 'player1');
```

this is profile.php i know this is to print one data of player

```php
<?php
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);
    require __DIR__ . "/includes/functions.php";
    require __DIR__ . "/includes/discord.php";
    require __DIR__ . "/config.php";
    
    if (isset($_SESSION['user'])) {
                    
                } else {
                    header("Location:index.php");
                }
                
      //PDO QUERY//
    $discord = $_SESSION['user_id'];
    $character = $dbh->query("SELECT * FROM players WHERE discord = '$discord'");
    foreach($character as $row){
        $charid = $row["id"];
        $citizenid = $row["citizenid"];
        $cid = $row["cid"];
        $owner = $row["name"];
    
     }
    ?>
<p><b>Character ID: </b><?php echo $cid; ?> </p>
<p><b>Owned By:</b> <?php echo $owner; ?></p>
<p><b>discord ID:</b> <?php echo $discord; ?></p>
<p><b>CitizenID:</b> <?php echo $citizenid ; ?></p>
```

Comment: If you just move all the echo lines inside the loop, that should do the job. Right now you're looping all the results but you're only outputting whatever the last result is, after the loop ends

Comment: yes i know its echo only the last result but im wondring how to echo all CID for player1 than if he click on cid2 for example than show info about his character 2

Comment: Well start by following my suggestion so you get all the results, not just one

Comment: it need a another query to get all CID for same discord than for each cid show data

Comment: Then, introduce a hyperlink or form in the output which sends back the cid to the server and runs another query to get more data

Comment: (if you don't know what I mean, it's time to hit the basic html and php tutorials)

Comment: i did this 
`$discord = $_SESSION['user_id'];
    $character = $dbh->query("SELECT * FROM players WHERE discord = '$discord'");
    foreach($character as $row){
        $charid = $row["id"];
        $citizenid = $row["citizenid"];
        $cid = $row["cid"];
        $owner = $row["name"];
    echo '<p>'. $row["cid"] .'</p>'; 
     }
    ?>`

it print
1
2
3

but i need another query for each cid

Comment: Yes, my comment above already explains what you need to do for that